# passing char array to function to get the value of update char array

Tags: c

```
int get_alpha()
{
    std::string sealed_alpha_file = "/home/roshan/thesis/osn_server/sealed_alpha";

    long fsize;
    ocall_get_textsize(sealed_alpha_file.c_str(), &fsize, 0);
    unsigned char sealed_data[fsize];
    size_t ocall_return;
    ocall_load_file(&ocall_return, sealed_alpha_file.c_str(), fsize, sealed_data, 0);

      char resecret[12];
      uint64_t resecret_size = sizeof(resecret);
      sgx_status_t ret;
      ret = sgx_unseal_data(
              (sgx_sealed_data_t*)sealed_data,
              NULL,
              NULL,
              (uint8_t*)&resecret,
              (uint32_t*)&resecret_size);

      if(ret != SGX_SUCCESS)
      {
          mbedtls_printf("Enclave: Unsealing sealed_alpha failed %#x\n", ret);
          return -1;
      }

    mbedtls_printf("Enclave: Unsealing sealed_alpha success");
    mbedtls_printf("Enclave: After unsealing alpha number: %llu\n", *(char *)resecret);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to call the get_alpha() function from another function and get the value from the resecret char array.
I tried to change the get_alpha() to get_alpha(char *resecret) and commented the char resecret[12]; in the get_alpha function and also made uint64_t resecret_size = sizeof(resecret); to uint64_t resecret_size = (12);.

And call it like this from other function

```
char resecret[12];
get_alpha(resecret);

mbedtls_printf("Enclave: After unsealing alpha number: %llu\n", *(char *)resecret);
```

But I do not get the correct answer. It seems sgx_unseal_data fails.

The signature of sgx_unseal_data:

```
sgx_status_t SGXAPI sgx_unseal_data(const sgx_sealed_data_t *p_sealed_data,
    uint8_t *p_additional_MACtext,
    uint32_t *p_additional_MACtext_length,
    uint8_t *p_decrypted_text,
    uint32_t *p_decrypted_text_length);
```

Comment: Not sure what the signature for sgx_unseal_data is, but seems like you are passing in a char** as the 4th param. Usually these things take in a char* for the buffer and an int* for the size copied. Changing (uint8_t*)&resecret to (uint8_t*)rescret should most likely fix it.

Comment: Correct. Solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marked line seems odd:

```
ret = sgx_unseal_data(
              (sgx_sealed_data_t*)sealed_data,
              NULL,
              NULL,
              (uint8_t*)&resecret,    // Probably shouldn't use address-of (&) here?
              (uint32_t*)&resecret_size);
```

I believe the call should be:

```
ret = sgx_unseal_data(
              (sgx_sealed_data_t*)sealed_data,
              NULL,
              NULL,
              (uint8_t*)resecret,                  
              (uint32_t*)&resecret_size);
```